# WebSocket onopen - message only sent sometimes

Tags: javascript, ruby, websocket, eventmachine

I'm having a strange problem with WebSocket.  When I open up a new socket, I have both the server and the client send handshake messages to each other.  However, the code seems to execute only sometimes.

Server Code (ruby):

```
# Set up the websocket server on port 8080
EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => "localhost", :port => 8080, :secure => false) do |ws|
    ws.onopen do
        ws.send "WebSocket opened on port 8080."
    end

    ws.onmessage do |msg|
        puts msg
    end

    ws.onclose do
        puts "WebSocket closed."
    end
end
```

Client code (javascript):

```
connection.onopen = function() {
    connection.send("Ping!");
};

connection.onerror = function() {
    console.log("WebSocket error.");
};

connection.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log("Server: " + e.data);
};
```

The console output on the server side after some refreshing, waiting a couple of seconds each time:

```
WebSocket closed.
WebSocket closed.
WebSocket closed.
Ping!
WebSocket closed.
WebSocket closed.
WebSocket closed.
WebSocket closed.
Ping!
WebSocket closed.
WebSocket closed.
```

Each time "Ping!" is posted, the client also receives the handshake message directed to it.  So the failure is on both sides - when it does work, both sides receive their messages.

What might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be an issue with `EventMachine::WebSocket`?

I wonder if all the connections closures are websocket connections. Maybe your browser is trying to access the page using Http as well?

Is it possible that the connections are being closed before the Websocket response to the "Ping" is available?

You can try using a different server side solution to check if this might be the issue.

For example, you can use [Plezi](http://www.plezi.io) to test the client and gather more information. i.e. (in `irb`):

```
require 'plezi'

class TestController
    def index
        puts "Got HTTP request"
        "Hello World"
    end
    def on_open
        puts "Websocket Opened."
        write "Websocket Opened."
    end
    def on_message data
        puts "Got: #{data}"
        write "pong"
    end
    def on_close
        puts "Websocket Closed."
    end
end
route '/', TestController
# if using `irb`, use:
exit # to start server
```

Good luck.

P.S. The default port is 3000.

If you want, you can either use:

```
Plezi.port = 8080
```

Or run your script (omit the `exit` directive if not using `irb`) with the `-p` argument:

```
$ ruby ./server.rb -p 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the Javascript? Is there some dependency that needs to be loaded first? Where is connection defined?

Comment: The javascript is a ReactJS jsx file that's being loaded to every page - there are no dependency issues because the socket is working, it's just the handshake message that doesn't show up.  The connection is defined globally.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a race condition? Given that a js WebSocket connect at construction time, maybe you wont be able to add the `onopen` event handler before that event already has been triggered, and sent (without any effect) to an undefined handler?